# Measure CPU and Memory usage while running pgbench

Tags: postgresql-9.4, performance, postgresql-performance

what is the best way to capture the usage of CPU and memory while running pgbench? The only way I can think of is to read the info from `top` header.

what I do now

1. I run `top` command by print it out in a log file.
2. Then `grep` the cpu and memory in another `txt` file
3. Later I download the txt file and import it in excel file to get the average value of Cpu usage and Memory usage
4. The result of pgbench will be put together in the excel file

Is there any tips or standard of procedure to implement the TPC-B as well as monitor the resources.

Answer (score 3):

I show some tools I know.

[pg_activity](https://github.com/julmon/pg_activity/)  is a simple monitoring tool like top.

[pg_statsinfo](http://pgstatsinfo.projects.pgfoundry.org/index.html) and 
[pg_stats_reporter](http://pgstatsinfo.projects.pgfoundry.org/pg_stats_reporter.html) are  high quality utilities that monitor statistics and the activity of PostgreSQL as well as Operating system.

There are some general purpose monitoring tools such as  [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) and [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/). Those support postgres by providing modules and they can easily be used.

BTW, I know a great book: [The Art of Computer Systems Performance Analysis](http://as.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471503363.html). This gives you some hints for benchmarking.

Comment: how do you run this? concurrent monitor with pgbench?

Comment: pgbench is just a benchmark tool, it's not a practical system. If you want to know the result of pgbench, you can frequently run it and can run one of the monitoring tools together. There is no need to run those monitoring tools at same time (concurrently).

Comment: thanks @shx. I think I don't want to install extra tools to measure it

Answer (score 2):

Greg Smith has [pgbench-tools](https://github.com/gregs1104/pgbench-tools) which does multiple runs of `pgbench`, with concurrent runs of `vmstat` and `iostat` during the `pgbench` runs. It also lets you graph results with `gnuplot`. It sounds like it would fit your needs well.

Comment: thanks @Kassandry. I don't think I need extra tools. Perhaps you can elaborate steps to be taken without installing extra tools. Thanks again